# How can I determine the email client from email headers?

Tags: email, email-headers

It seems like most popular email clients don't include the `X-Mailer` header. Is there any good method to determine if an email was sent by a popular client, such as Gmail, Outlook or Apple Mail?

Comment: Also try the `User-Agent` header.

Comment: I don't see the `User-Agent` header in any of the emails I'm testing

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, the `User-Agent` header can be used to determine the client MUA.

If this header isn't present in any of the emails being tested, [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/96028/210242) suggests that you could also check other fields like the `message-id` since some email clients will generate a message-id of their own.

Some more information about different useful headers can be found [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/48755/210242).